# How to make two div 100% height of browser window right corner and left corner

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**CODE**

```html
<body align="left" style="background-color: white;">
  <div style="background-color:#1e836c;height:100vh;width:1vw;"></div>
  <div align="center" style="background-color: pink;height:100vh;width:1vw;"></div>
  <div align="right" style="background-color: red;height:100vh;width:1vw;"></div>
</body>
```

How can I implement bootstrap's grid system in the code above by keeping the same `width` and size of the `div`s?

Comment: I don't get your question :) can you explain a bit better

Comment: basically there will be three divs, one right and one left and one center

Comment: you meant center ?

Comment: i want to make the left and right divs very smalll and the center one bit bigger (i need to input content into it). Is it possible to use bootstraps grid system?

Comment: or is there any other ways to do that?

Comment: you could write that all in one comment. anyways I think I get you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make the left and right divs very smalll and the center one bit bigger

You can achieve that using `flexbox`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px
}
.child {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: red solid
}
.parent > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  flex: 3 /* this will be 3x times bigger than the other child */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

> I can achieve this by bootstrap grid pattern by giving col-md-1 for
>   left and right and col-md-8 for the center, but i wanna make the left
>   and right too small as possible

Using bootstrap, you can  use `col-xs-2` (or `col-xs-1`) for smaller childs and `col-xs-8`(`col-xs-10)` for middle one child

I used `col-xs-2` +`col-xs-10` for the demo (having `margins`)

```css
[class^="col"] div {
  height: 200px;
  border: red solid
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> I just want the width of that red line only.. Thats the tricky part

### So that's not `div`s, that's a **`border`** property

using bootstrap grid and pseudo elements`::before/::after` here you go:

```css
.col-xs-10 {
  height: 200px;
  border: red solid
}
.col-xs-10::before,
.col-xs-10::after {
  border-left: red solid;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -3px;
  height: 200px
}
.col-xs-10::before {
  left: -20px
}
.col-xs-10::after {
  right: -20px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can achieve this by bootstrap grid pattern by giving col-md-1 for left and right and col-md-8 for the center, but i wanna make the left and right too small as possible

Comment: xs and md seems like the same function

Comment: i just want the width of that red line only.. Thats the tricky part

Comment: so no `div`, that's a **`border`**

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well, but I think that's it:

```css
            #div-01{background-color: pink;height:100vh;width:1vw;float: left;} 
#div-02{background-color: red;height:100vh;width:1vw;float: right;}
```

```html
        <div id="div-01"></div>
<div id="div-02"></div>
```

if you want other thing please explain in detail

**UPDATE**
doing so you have the main div in the center and the side floating.

```css
            #div-center{border: solid blue;height:2000px;width:65%;display: block;margin: 0 auto;}
            #div-right{border: solid pink;height:200px;width:15%;position: fixed;right: 0px;} 
            #div-left{border: solid red;height:200px;width:15%;position: fixed;left: 0px;}
```

```html
        <div id="div-right"></div>
        <div id="div-left"></div>
        <div id="div-center"></div>
```

Comment: i want to make the left and right divs very smalll and the center one bit bigger (i need to input content into it).

Comment: so as per your answer a new div which float "center"?